# Use of uninitialized value within @spl in substitution (s///)

Tags: arrays, perl, initialization

I am getting following error while running the script.

```
Use of uninitialized value in print at PreProcess.pl line 137.
Use of uninitialized value within @spl in substitution (s///) at PreProcess.pl line 137.
```

Is there any syntax error in the script?
(Running it in Windows - Strawberry 64 last version)

```
my $Dat=2;
my $a = 7;
foreach  (@spl) {
    if ( $_ =~ $NameInstru ) {  
        print $spl[$Dat] =~ s/-/\./gr, " 00:00; ",$spl[$a],"\n";    # data
        $Dat += 87;
        $a += 87;
    }
}
```

inside of array i hve  this type of data

```
"U.S. DOLLAR INDEX - ICE FUTURES U.S."
150113
2015-01-13
098662
ICUS
01
098
  128104
   14111
   88637
     505
   13200
      50
     269
   43140
   34142
    1862
   37355
     482
     180
  110623
  126128
   17480
    1976
    1081
   -3699
    8571
    -120
     646
      50
     248
    1581
   -8006
     319
    2093
      31
     -30
    1039
    1063
      42
      18
  100.0
   11.0
   69.2
    0.4
   10.3
    0.0
    0.2
   33.7
   26.7
    1.5
   29.2
    0.4
    0.1
   86.4
   98.5
   13.6
    1.5
    215
      7
.
.
     16
.
.
     50
     16
      8
    116
      6
      4
    197
     34
    28.6
    85.1
    41.3
    91.3
    28.2
    85.1
    40.8
    91.2
"(U.S. DOLLAR INDEX X $1000)"
"098662"
"ICUS"
"098"
"F90"
"Combined"

"U.S. DOLLAR INDEX - ICE FUTURES U.S."
150106
2015-01-06
098662
ICUS
01
098
  127023
   17810
   80066
     625
   12554
       0
      21
   41559
   42148
    1544
   35262
     452
     210
  109585
  125065
   17438
    1958
   19675
     486
   23911
      49
    2717
       0
     -73
    9262
   -5037
      30
    5873
     270
      95
   18439
   19245
    1237
     431
  100.0
   14.0
   63.0
    0.5
    9.9
    0.0
    0.0
   32.7
   33.2
    1.2
   27.8
    0.4
    0.2
   86.3
   98.5
   13.7
    1.5
    202
      7
.
.
     16
      0
.
     48
     16
      9
    105
      6
      4
    185
     34
    29.3
    83.2
    43.2
    90.6
    28.9
    83.2
    42.8
    90.5
"(U.S. DOLLAR INDEX X $1000)"
"098662"
"ICUS"
"098"
"F90"
"Combined"
```

Comment: Question is unclear. What are values in `@spl` `$NameInstru`?

Comment: yes use windows 10 strawberry 64 bit , is possible attach a txt  in this forum ?

Comment: i modify the script in this mode  work much better  but return again this error Use of uninitialized value within @spl in string eq at PreProcess.pl line 138.      foreach  (@spl) {if ($spl[$Dat] eq "") {
        last;
       }
       print $spl[$Dat] =~ s/-/\./gr," 00:00; ",$spl[$OIa],"\n";    # data
                $Dat += 87;
        $OIa += 87;           }

Answer (score 1):

You are probably trying to load a file of data sets of a size of 87 lines each into an array, and then you get an error at the end of your data, when you try to read outside of the last array index.

You can probably solve it by iterating over the array indexes instead of the array values, e.g.

```
my $Dat = 2;
my $a = 7;
my $set_size = 87;

for (my $n = 0; $n + $a < @spl; $n += $set_size) {
    if ( $spl[$n] =~ $NameInstru ) {  
        print $spl[$n + $Dat] =~ s/-/\./gr, " 00:00; ",$spl[$n + $a],"\n";    # data
    }
}
```

While this might solve your problem, it might be better to try and find a proper way to parse your file.

If the records inside the input file are separated by a blank line, you can try to read whole records at once by changing the [input record separator](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24%2F) to `""` or `"\n\n"`. Then you can split each element in the resulting array on newline `\n` and get an entire record as a result. For example:

```
$/ = "";
my @spl;
open my $fh ... 
while (<$fh>) {
    push @spl, [ split "\n", $_ ];
}

...

for my $record (@spl) {
    # @$record is now an 87 element array with each record in the file
}
```

Comment: You could also use `$n + $set_size < @spl` instead of `$n + $a < @spl` (unless you really do want to support partial sets). This avoids the assumption that `$a >= $Dat`.

Answer (score 1):

TLP's solution of iterating over the indexes of an array, incrementing by 87 at time is great.

Here's a more complex solution, but one that doesn't require loading the entire file into memory.

```perl
my $lines_per_row = 87;

my @row;
while (<>) {
   chomp;
   push @row, $_;
   if (@row == $lines_per_row) {
      my ($instru, $dat, $a) = @row[0, 2, 7];
      if ($instru =~ $NameInstru) {
         print $dat =~ s/-/\./gr, " 00:00; $a\n";
      }

      @row = ();
   }
}
```